# When does the following relationship hold for orthogonal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $\mathbf{O}_1,\mathbf{O}_2, \mathbf{O}_3 \in \mathbb{O}(2)$ [the set of all $2$-D orthogonal matrices]. We have the following equations:
$$\mathbf{O}_1x_1+\mathbf{O}_2x_2=x_1+x_2 \dots(1)$$
$$\mathbf{O}_1y_1+\mathbf{O}_3y_3=y_1+y_3 \dots(2)$$
where $x_1\neq \alpha x_2$, $y_1 \neq \beta y_3$ and $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Under what conditions we can say that:

The above equations have a solution, iff, $\mathbf{O}_1=\mathbf{I}_2$.